# Find the largest number in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find the month (column 'Month') that has the largest number (in DepDelay column)

**Data**

```
flightID         Month  ArrTime ActualElapsedTime  DepDelay   ArrDelay
BBYYEUVY67527        1   1514.0               58.0       NA      64.0   
MUPXAQFN40227        1     37.0              120.0       13      52.0   
LQLYUIMN79169        1    916.0              166.0       NA     -25.0   
KTAMHIFO10843        1      NaN                NaN        5       NaN   
BOOXJTEY23623        1      NaN                NaN        4       NaN  
BBYYEUVY67527        2   1514.0               58.0       NA      64.0   
MUPXAQFN40227        2     37.0              120.0       NA      52.0   
LQLYUIMN79169        2    916.0              166.0       NA     -25.0   
KTAMHIFO10843        2      NaN                NaN       15       NaN   
BOOXJTEY23623        2      NaN                NaN        4       NaN
```

**I tried:**

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t')

dep_delay = all_data.groupby(["Month"].DepDelay.count().max())

print(dep_delay)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2ea6213009d6> in <module>()
----> 1 dep_delay = all_data.groupby(["Month"].DepDelay.count().max())
      2 
      3 print(dep_delay)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'DepDelay'
```

**Good output:**

```
Month      DepDelay
    1            22
```

Comment: I think you need `sum` instead of `count` here. `count` counts number of non-null values, `sum` totals up (ignoring `NaN`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `sum` instead of `count` to sum values by group. Here's one way using `GroupBy` + `sum`, and then `idxmax`:

```
res = df.groupby('Month')['DepDelay'].sum().reset_index()
res = res.loc[[res['DepDelay'].idxmax()]]

print(res)

   Month  DepDelay
0      1      22.0
```

Alternatively, you can group and sort, then extract the first row:

```
res = df.groupby('Month')['DepDelay'].sum()\
        .sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

   Month  DepDelay
0      1      22.0
```

Answer (score 2):

to make your code work, change

`dep_delay = all_data.groupby(["Month"].DepDelay.count().max())`

to

`dep_delay = all_data.groupby(["Month"]).DepDelay.count().max()`

To find your solution:

```
idx = all_data['DepDelay'].idxmax()

all_data.loc[[idx], ['Month', 'DepDelay']]
```

Output

```
     Month  DepDelay
8      2      15.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['DepDelay'].idxmax(), ['Month', 'DepDelay']]).T
#  Month DepDelay
#8     2       15
```

And you can reset index to change `8` to `0`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['DepDelay'].idxmax(), ['Month', 'DepDelay']]).T.reset_index(drop=True)
#  Month DepDelay
#0     2       15
```

Comment: the answer should be 22 no?

Comment: @Yuca *I'm trying to find the month (column 'Month') that has the largest number (in DepDelay column)* is what OP said. And the 22 thing was solved in another answer.

Comment: and the 15 on mine :), ok so there's enough ambiguity to allow for both approaches

Comment: @Yuca Yours is `Series`, mine is `DataFrame` :)